# Get variables always in differnet .phtml templates

Tags: php, magento

I have to use some variables again and again in different files.

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_productType = $_product->getTypeID();
$_productName = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
$_manufacturer = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
$_decor = $_product->getAttributeText('decor');
$_serie = $_product->getAttributeText('serie');
$originalImageWidth = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->getOriginalWidth();
$originalImageHeight = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->getOriginalHeight();
$originalImageRelation = $originalImageWidth / $originalImageHeight;
```

All this, I need in `/templates/catalog/product/view.phtml` and `/templates/catalog/product/type/grouped.phtml` and `templates/catalog/product/media.phtml`.

Is there a way to gather this in a central file and reuse it in all this places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using magento you should be able to create a view helper which can be called from within the view.

You can check [This](http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-helper-howto-tutorial-113) tutorial which should give you everything you need to solve your problem

Comment: Is it possible to do that in the layout.xml of the theme too? I don't want to open up a whole plugin-structure.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with magento, but helpers are common pratice, so yeah you should be able to do that. Providing a helper for your application